# showing the image of unit disc on Complex plane under $f(z)=z^2$ is open

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I want to use the fact that $|f(z)|=|z|^2$ and $|z|<1$(so basically the map f maps onto some subset of the unit disc that includes {-1,1,i,-i}) to construct an open disc for any arbitrary point in the image.
Let $z_0 \in f(D_1(0))$, then there exists $1>r>0$ such that $f^{-1}(z_0)\in D_{r}(f^{-1}(z_0))$ , now let $r^\prime=r^2$ then $r^\prime<r$ forms a disc center at $z_0$ such that $D_{r^\prime}(z_0)\subset f(D_{1}(0))$. Hence the image is open.

Comment: The image is the open unit disk itself.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah, I see, so I should instead show that this map is an bijection on the unit disc?

Comment: Every point in the unit disk has  a square root which is also in the unit disk. You are making things too complicated.

Comment: It is plainly an application of the [Open Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)) if you take the image of the **open** unit disk. Moreover it is clearly the open unit disk itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have to write a formal proof(restricted from using any mapping properties of holomorphic function) as an assignment for this particular question, that's why I am trying to write out some sort of argument.

Comment: Apply the polar form of complex numbers $z=re^{it}$.